# Acces data from mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The idea of my application is adding data in mongodb database and getting data as a list from database to front end.

Here is my index.js file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs')
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render(`home.ejs`)
});

app.get('/form', (req, res) => {
    res.render(`form.ejs`)
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////
let jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
let urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        let dbo = db.db("test");

        const userName = req.body.firstName;
        const userLastName = req.body.lastName;
        console.log(userName);
        console.log(userLastName);
        res.render(`home.ejs`, {userName, userLastName});

        let myobj = {firstName: userName, lastName: userLastName};
        dbo.collection("users").insertOne(myobj, function (err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
          else {
                dbo.collection('users').find().toArray(function(err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    const a = result.map(i => i.firstName);

                    console.log(a);
                    app.get('/blog', (req, res) => {
                        res.render(`blog.ejs`, {a})     // here i send data to my blog file
                    });
                    db.close();
                });
            }
            console.log("1 document inserted");
            db.close();
        });
    });

});

app.listen(9000, function () {
    console.log('node starts')
});
```

The file where i want to send data is `blog.ejs`. If i run the command `node index.js` i will get the data from mongodb, but if after i will add something new in my `form` file, and even if the data will be sent in database, on front end it won't be updated and this is the main problem.

Here is my `form.ejs` file:

```js
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstName">
    <input type="text" name="lastName">
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT DATA</button>
</form>
<a href="/">Back to Home</a>
```

Here is my `blog.ejs` file:

```js
<div>
    <h1>Blog</h1>
    <%=a %>
    <a href="/form">Back to Form</a>
</div>
```

My question is:
1. How to solve the problem with updating of data on the front end after i send something trough `form.ejs`?

Answer (score 0):

So you have mixed two route together, so first thing first, create a route to render home and form with get method. (hopefully you have link for going to form in home.ejs)

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render(`home.ejs`);
});

app.get('/form', function (req, res) {
    res.render('form.ejs');
});
```

Then in the form.ejs change action to "/form" and create this route with post method.

And when you retrive the data just render the blog.ejs.

```
app.post('/form', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) res.render('404.ejs', err);
        let dbo = db.db('test');

        const userName = req.body.firstName;
        const userLastName = req.body.lastName;

        console.log(userName);
        console.log(userLastName);

        let myobj = { firstName: userName, lastName: userLastName };
        dbo.collection('users').insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
            if (err) res.render('404.ejs', err);
            dbo
                .collection('users')
                .find()
                .toArray(function(err, result) {
                    if (err) res.render('404.ejs', err);
                    const a = result.map(i => i.firstName);

                    console.log(a);
                    res.render(`blog.ejs`, { a });
                    db.close();
                });
        });
    });
});
```